# opening camera in Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, augmented-reality, expo

I am trying to run this code (https://snack.expo.io/Hk1C_YqjW) on my android device using `Expo XDE`, but when it comes to this line:

```
const arSession = await this._glView.startARSessionAsync();
```

shows this error and stops:

```
[Unhandled Promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.NativeModules.ExponentGLViewManager.startARSessionAsync')]
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Have you assigned the reference to `_glView`? Like the example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expo doesn't support ARCore on Android yet, only ARKit on iOS. See more information at https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/AR