# How to access camera in react native expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

This is the code I am implementing to access camera in React Native Expo App. But this code is not working. It only shows blank screen and nothing else. Please suggest me if any changes required or any alternate method to implement this.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';

export default function App() {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
    })();
  }, []);

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <View />;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Camera style={{ flex: 1 }} type={type}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            flexDirection: 'row',
          }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              flex: 0.1,
              alignSelf: 'flex-end',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}
            onPress={() => {
              setType(
                type === Camera.Constants.Type.back
                  ? Camera.Constants.Type.front
                  : Camera.Constants.Type.back
              );
            }}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, marginBottom: 50, color: 'red' }}> Flip </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Camera>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: is this happening on a device or an emulator?

Comment: you are using the code from https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera/ which works, the camera doesn't work on the emulator.

Comment: I am using the code on Device not on emulator

Comment: it's working on my device try this snack https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=Basic%20Camera%20usage&sdkVersion=36.0.0&dependencies=expo-camera&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.expo.io%2Fstatic%2Fexamples%2Fv36.0.0%2Fcamera.js

Comment: Sir actually I am getting this error in my console-> "[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: _expoCamera.Camera.requestPermissionsAsync is not a function. (In '_expoCamera.Camera.requestPermissionsAsync()', '_expoCamera.Camera.requestPermissionsAsync' is undefined)]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like somehow you have denied permission in App. Also In the code, if hasPermission is null you will see a blank page.
Note: In Ios, if you have denied or granted permission once, then the app will never show permission popup again until you use linking and let the user enable permission from setting.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Camera.requestPermissionsAsync is now deprecated. You might try using Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync(). After I updated my code the deprecation notice disappeared.

Comment: Thanks 


`Camera.getCameraPermissionsAsync()` is deprecated



`Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync()` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The Camera component shouldn't in the `<SafeAreaView>`

```
<YOUR_CAMERA_COMPONENT /> /* <-- when outside the <SafeAreaView> , it work!*/

<SafeAreaView>
    <YOUR_CAMERA_COMPONENT />  /* <-- it will show blank view */
</SafeAreaView>
```

I solved the problem when removed the `<Camera />` from `<SafeAreaView />`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i am using:

```
"expo": "~40.0.0",
```

now im upgrading the cli and then using expo upgrade and everything fix itself:

```
"expo": "^41.0.0",
"expo-camera": "~11.0.2",
"expo-cli": "^4.4.1",
"expo-image-picker": "~10.1.4",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
"firebase": "8.2.3",
```

Answer (score -1):

The emulator camera doesn't support this library , try using in Android or Ios device and it will work perfectly fine.

Please check [this example](https://reactnative.sataiva.com/reactnative-intro/reactnative-expo-camera/) or the original [Expo-camera](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v36.0.0/sdk/camera/) library.

Hope it helps .feel free for doubts

Comment: the above code works, OP is using the code on emulator.

Comment: Sir actually I am getting this error in my console-> "[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: _expoCamera.Camera.requestPermissionsAsync is not a function. (In '_expoCamera.Camera.requestPermissionsAsync()', '_expoCamera.Camera.requestPermissionsAsync' is undefined)]"

Comment: try this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842499/react-native-possible-unhandled-promise-rejection

Comment: Sir I am not getting this

Comment: cheack this example link and read it it will make you understand better.

Answer (score -2):

I saw your code and I feels this code same as a expo-camera documentation.
I think you are trying this code on Emulator/Simulator . please try once on 
**Physical Device**. because emulator doesn't support camera. you can read the document in brief https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#requestpermissionsasync

Comment: Yes it is the same code and I am running it on Phone not on emulator

Comment: @HimanshuMishra try this https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=Basic%20Camera%20usage&sdkVersion=36.0.0&dependencies=expo-camera&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.expo.io%2Fstatic%2Fexamples%2Fv36.0.0%2Fcamera.js

Comment: okay . then you should try `expo-permissions` and added this code in your project 
`import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';`
`getPermissionAsync = async () => {
        if (Constants.platform.ios) {
            const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
            if (status !== 'granted') {
                alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: Sir actually I am getting this error in my console-> "[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: _expoCamera.Camera.requestPermissionsAsync is not a function. (In '_expoCamera.Camera.requestPermissionsAsync()', '_expoCamera.Camera.requestPermissionsAsync' is undefined)]"

Comment: look at this once https://stackoverflow.com/a/51179694/9444013

Comment: Sir I am using Android Phone.